# Akka, AMI - discover remote actors for database access

Tags: amazon-ec2, akka, amazon-ami

I am working on a prototype for a client where, on `AWS` auto-scaling is used to create new VMs from Amazon Machine Images (AMIs), using Akka.

I want to have just one actor, control access to the database, so it will create new children, as needed, and queue up requests that go beyond a set limit.

But, I don't know the IP address of the VM, as it may change as Amazon adds/removes VMs based on activity.

How can I discover the actor that will be used to limit access to the database?

I am not certain if clustering will work (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-usage.html), and this question and answers are from 2011 ([Akka remote actor server discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305900/akka-remote-actor-server-discovery)), and possibly routing may solve this problem: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/routing.html

I have a separate REST service that just goes to the database, so it may be that this service will need to do the control before it goes to the actors.

Comment: Akka cluster has the concept of Cluster Singleton (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/cluster-singleton.html) which could be what you are looking for. This may work if some of the addresses of the nodes of the cluster are well-known. On the other hand, this could just push the problem one level higher, namely how to locate the cluster from the outside. This kind of service-discovery problem needs to be solved outside of akka.

Comment: @jrudolph - Thank you for the link and you may be correct that this needs to be solved outside of Akka.